# Get latest date in group mysql

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am look to get the last time a meeting was held for each staff member but not getting anywhere fast here is my layout

```
Meetings
id staff    date       notes <br>
1    46  2016-01-01    Test notes <br>
2    46  2016-02-28    test note<br>
3    56  2017-01-05    
4    56  2017-02-15

staff
id  first_name   last_name<br>
46  test 1        user1 <br>
56  test 2        user2
```

Here is my query but it wont give me the last date they had a meeting

```
SELECT
staff.first_name,
staff.last_name,
meetings.`date`,
meetings.notes,
meetings.`type`,
meetings.id
FROM
meetings
Inner Join staff ON meetings.staff = staff.id
GROUP BY
meetings.staff
```

Comment: This type of question is very common, follow the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag to find many solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` clause with `MAX` function to get the desired result, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name, MAX(m.date)
FROM staff s LEFT JOIN meetings m ON s.id = m.staff
GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
ORDER BY s.id;
```

**Update** 
If you do not want to include the staff members who haven't been to any meeting yet then you can just use `inner join`, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name, MAX(m.date)
FROM staff s JOIN meetings m ON s.id = m.staff
GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name
ORDER BY s.id;
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks, I tweeked it and it now is excatley what I needed SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, MAX(m.date)
FROM staff s LEFT JOIN meetings m ON s.id = m.staff
WHERE
m.`date` !=  'null'
GROUP BY s.first_name, s.last_name

Comment: What was the tweak? The reason I used `left` join is to include staff members who haven't attended any meeting.

Comment: @PaulSmith I have added another answer. Better to use `inner join` than to use `left join` with null check. Can you please try it?

Comment: WHERE m.date != 'null'  when I ran yours it showed all staff even if they had not had a meeting, but thanks again

Comment: Yeah, I got your point. Could you try the second query? It's more efficient.

Comment: One last question, I am pulling the data into a table in php using foreach what would be the name for the date ? would if be m.date? this is what I am using just now        <?php if ($meeting['date']< $now){ ?>
                                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $meeting['first_name'] . " ". $meeting['last_name']; ?></a> </td>
                                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $meeting['type']; ?></a> </td
                                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $meeting

Comment: You can use `MAX(m.date) AS date` and then, use `$meeting['date']` in your code.

Comment: Also, if you think my answer has helped you, could you please accept it as correct answer? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Darshan Mehta this done the job

SELECT s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name, MAX(m.date) 
FROM staff s JOIN meetings m ON s.id = m.staff 
GROUP BY s.id, s.first_name, s.last_name 
ORDER BY s.id;